# Laravel: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in

Tags: laravel, npm

In a new Laravel install I get the following error when I run `npm run dev`: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in 'path/here/resources/js'`

In my `package.json` under `devDependencies` I have `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"` and I haven't edited anything.

Original Laravel bootstrap.js (this is Laravel's own bootstrap file, not the one from getbootstrap.com) can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js).

Comment: Did you run ```npm install```?

Answer (score 2):

reinstall bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Comment: I suspect the install hasn't even been run, so `npm install` would fix it and get everything else, too

Comment: time ago happened that issue , even when I got npm installed. idk why.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: That has nothing to do with that bootstrap :) it's a different bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has removed Ui prerequisites from the framework.

The Bootstrap, React Vue scaffolding provided by Laravel is located in the `laravel/ui` Composer package, which may be installed using Composer:

`composer require laravel/ui`
Once the laravel/ui package has been installed, you may install the frontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

now you can use `npm i` ;-).